# define_method and the object Class: strange behavior

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, eigenclass

---

EDIT: Let me expand a bit on what my intentions were:

Given that a ruby object gets its methods from its class' instance methods.

What I was trying to "prove" was that by adding instance methods to that object's class, they would then become method on that object itself.

So:

```
class Test;end
Test.class.class_eval do 
  def foo
    puts "I am a method in #{self}"
  end
end
Test.foo
=> I am a method in Test
Test.class.foo
=> I am a method in Class
```

I actually already figured out why this happens. That's because Class.class is... Class! Since Class has foo as part of its instance methods table, and since Class.class points to itself, it will also have foo as a callable instance method.

### Original post follows:

Just for the sake of learning more about the Ruby object model, I've been doing some experiments, and the following behavior surprised me:

Let's say we have a class Test:

```
class Test;end
```

Then, we class_eval Test.class in order to add a method to the Test object:

```
Test.class.class_eval do
  def foo 
    puts 'foo called!'
  end
end
```

(equivalent to calling Test.class.send(:define_method,:foo) ... )

Then:

```
irb(main):076:0> Test.foo
=> foo called!
```

But sending foo to class also works:

```
irb(main):006:0> Test.class.foo
=> foo called!
```

I still can't figure out why, though. The Class' singleton_class doesn't contain it (the only possible explanation that came to my mind was that somehow the method was added to the Class' singleton class):

```
Test.class.singleton_methods
=> [:nesting, :constants]
```

How does the method lookup work in this case? Why does sending :foo to Test.class also calls the method ? Am I missing something ?

---

As a reference, I did the same thing with an instance of Test:

```
irb(main):001:0> class Test;end
=> nil
irb(main):002:0> _foo = Test.new
=> #<Test:0x007fa2c39e2f38>
irb(main):003:0> _foo.class.class_eval do
irb(main):004:1*   def foo
irb(main):005:2>    puts 'foo called!'
irb(main):006:2>   end
irb(main):007:1> end
=> :foo
irb(main):008:0> _foo.foo
foo called!
=> nil
irb(main):009:0> _foo.class.foo
NoMethodError: undefined method `foo' for Test:Class
```

This worked the way I expected it to.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short, sending foo to Test.class works because:

```
Test.class == Class and Class.class == Class
```

Class.class points to itself.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `Test.class` it returns the class of `Test` **not** the actual Test class.

```
irb(main):001:0> class Test;end
=> nil
irb(main):002:0> Test.class
=> Class
```

When you call `_foo = Test.new` you are grabbing an instance of the class and then when you call `_foo.class` it returns the class of the instance of `foo` which is `Test`

In your first example, you **are** adding foo to the super class, and not to the `Test` class.

To expand more on this, what you should be doing is calling `class_eval` on the `Test` class.
On top of that, what you want is a class method, not an instance method. Because the `Test` class is actually an instance of `Class`, you actually defined an instance method in the `Class` class instead of defining a class method in `Test`. What you should be doing is this:

```
Test.class_eval do
  def self.foo
    puts "foo called!" 
  end
end
```

Comment: Good answer.  There's an easy test of your assertion: `Class.foo => foo called!`

Comment: Hi. Thank you for taking the time to answer. I wasn't actually trying to accomplish anything in particular. I was wondering about why sending the :foo message to Test.class called the foo method. I already figured out, and edited the original post.

Comment: So did I answer your question? Do you still have a question? Can you clarify please.

Comment: In your edit, you're actually wrong. It's because Test.class is `Class`. You are defining an instance method on the `Class` object and because your `Test` class is an instance of `Class` it has that method.

Comment: Why wrong? I'm aware that Test.class is Class. But then, I went to say Class.class == Class. In sum: Because Test.class == Class and Class.class == Class. So yeah, everything figured out. I'll close it.

Answer (score 1):

You mixed the things up a bit.

- `Test.class_eval` is executed on `Test`’s eigenclass (which is `Test`.)
- `Test.class.class_eval` is executed on `Test`’s eigenclass’ eigenclass (which is apparently `Class`.)
- `Test.class.singleton_methods` returns methods of `Class`’ eigenclass.

`Test.class.class_eval` actually executes code on `Class` (declaring `Class`’ instance method in your case.)

`Test.foo` is called w/out problems because you have declared `#foo` on `Class` and `Test` is an instance of it (as well as `Test.class`.)

Comment: Hi. Sending :foo to Test.class works because Test.class.class is Class. That's actually the answer to my question. Thank you for taking the time to answer.